# FabricJS Objects offsetted on mobile

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have created a canvas using fabric.js and encountered a very strange problem on mobile devices. Whenever I add an object i.e a circle it has a bizarre behaviour: Wherever I click on desktop that's where it is added but on mobile its top left and the object can not be selected after being added on canvas.

```
setupCircle(x0, y0) {
  this.circleCoord.x0 = x0;
  this.circleCoord.y0 = y0;
  this.circleCoord.circObj = new fabric.Circle({
    left: x0,
    top: y0,
    radius: 100,
    strokeWidth: 5,
    hasControls: true,
    borderColor: 'red',
    fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    stroke: this.canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });
  this.canvas.add(this.circleCoord.circObj);
}
```

This is how I add a shape on mouse move. And above is how I scale the canvas and its objects on different screen resolutions

```
getCanvasAtResoution(newWidth, newHeight) {

  const id = 'c' + this.panelId;
  const scaleMultiplier = newWidth / document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].clientWidth;
  let objects = this.canvas.getObjects();
  for (let i in objects) {
    objects[i].scaleX = objects[i].scaleX * scaleMultiplier;
    objects[i].scaleY = objects[i].scaleY * scaleMultiplier;
    objects[i].left = objects[i].left * scaleMultiplier;
    objects[i].top = objects[i].top * scaleMultiplier;
    objects[i].setCoords();
  }
  let obj = this.canvas.backgroundImage;
  if (obj) {
    obj.scaleX = obj.scaleX * scaleMultiplier;
    obj.scaleY = obj.scaleY * scaleMultiplier;
  }
  this.canvas.discardActiveObject();
  this.canvas.setDimensions({
    width: newWidth,
    height: newHeight
  });

  this.canvas.renderAll();
  this.canvas.calcOffset();
},
```

Comment: How you are calling `setupCircle(x0, y0)`, what is x0 and y0 there?

Comment: i get the x0 and y0 on mouse:down event with e.layerX and e.layerY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
canvas.on('mouse:move',function(option){
 var pointer = canvas.getPointer(option.e);
 result.innerHTML = "x: "+pointer.x+" y: "+pointer.y;
})
```

```css
canvas{
 border:2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width=400 height=400></canvas><br>
<span id='result'></span>
```

Use [getPointer](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#getPointer) to get the mouse position.

Comment: It's finally working, thank you so so much for your help